# How do i kill Aiushtha in DotA?

Tags: dota

I'm having trouble with Aiushtha the Enchantress?

The build which is really giving me trouble is the one where my opponent rushes the +25 intelligence wand. Then he goes for boots and perseverance. The first 8 levels are fine. When he gets to lvl10-12 I am no longer able to kill him. He does Base Damage + 90 every time he attacks me, around lvl 10 I'm still under 1,000HP.

I tried buying armor (+15) without success. What's more his many wisp heal quite quickly. I've tried sneaking behind him and unloading with little success, often leaving him at full hit points.

What's worse if he turns his staff into a sheep stick I'm even more behind.

I'm most concerned with 1v1 in the 10-12 level area.

-edit- I do notice the opponent running away to refill mana but usually he isnt gone long. Maybe i can play in a way to make him use mana repeatably without losing too much health and leave often? Maybe i should be less afraid of the ultimate or farm creeps instead of trying to kill her (or not far at all and only try to damage her?)

nevermore is one of my favourites, how do i kill aiushtha with nevermore?

Comment: I'm no DotA expert, but I guess it really depends on which character you are playing. Maybe you could provide that too. Or should the answer include also the opponent with which the Aiushtha can be killed?

Comment: From the sounds of it, he is playing a single hero and is not a veteran player.

Comment: @tzenes: Thats a large edit you made. It doesnt look so bad. You know one of my most preferred characters, what do you think i should do?

Comment: I know DotA can be very frustrating sometimes, but the next time you come here for help, please read over your question before posting.  A few changes will really garner a better response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I haven't played DOTA in a few patches...

Enchantress biggest weakest are nukes because of her little HP
You said you enjoy Nevermore, your best bet would be too just stay out of her range during the lane, and just `last hit` appropriately...`focus on not dying` to build up your creep count (which gives you damage) at lvl 3-5 you could start using your long and mid range nukes to last hit+`harass the Enchant`, and disengage if she wants to fight. This will keep you at high health and her at medium, giving you a significant lane advantage (with three nukes all it takes is one good rune to kill her at medium life). When you do engage dont attack until you have used all your nukes, She has a move that slows you and if she decides to run you wont be able to chase if you attack her. If she ever procs her healing item, just back off and pop a clarity, then harass a litte more aggressively while its on Cooldown, this will force her to heal at well, giving you an EXP advantage.

Be sure to use chicken early game to keep mana/ life in good shape so you dont have to leave your lane and get boots before her so you can chase when you go in for the kill. If she is rushing the +25 INT item, you should have a significant early-mid game advantage with items, big enough to kill her a few times and come out on top.

Non Nevermore specific tips:

- Nukes > Stuns when it comes to
  Enchant since attacking her will slow
  your hero.
- You usually have to kill    Enchant in 2 bursts, 1 to get her to    pop
  heal, then another to kill.
- At       the start just last hit and
  attack       her only when your
  creeps are there
- Keep good control of runes during early-mid game
- Use chicken so you dont have to goto
  town and heal (meaning you will
  always be gaining      exp)
- Keep an eye out for Enchants chicken,
  your long range nuke means you can
  kill it without even going up ramp
  sometimes

Hope this helps and be free to comment with any questions

Comment: excellent suggestions. What is a nuke? is that my requim (lvl6 move)? shadowraze? or both? runes are those things on the river? what is a good rune? i know double damage is good but what else? i dont see invisibility helping much because i have trouble killing here even when going invisible (she doesnt run and always seems to be full health so i guess this only helps when i go to attack the 2nd time?) any other ones good for attacking her? Since she has low health i think i'll specifically go for her when i can to have her run to base often early game. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nuke is a move that does direct damage, With Nevermore thats shadowraze, the start of your ulty is a nuke but most people dont consider it one due to its start up time.

Runes are things on the river yes. Haste is probably best for 1v1, They are all great though. Double Damage could help. Note that if you have a bottle (Were way overpowered when i played i dunno how the metagame is now) you can store runes inside the bottle for later use

You should probably just play 5v5 a bit more to get a good grasp on teh game before u go 1v1, as its more technical than 5v5 is.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by Josh is good enough though I wanted just to mention something. Putting lots of armor on you won't help you at all, as Aiushtha deals true damage with impetus. This means it pierces to your whole magic and physical resistance/armor. The value that appears as a number when the arrow hits you it's the exact damage you take and it can't be reduced. This is also the case for silencer's glaives of wisdom and obsidian destroyer's arcande orb(Also hook and other skills deal true damage). Btw pudge would wipe her very easily. I hope this makes a few clarification and helps someone ;)